# Python_Pivoting DataFrame with multiple columns for the index

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have following dataframe in pandas (1048575 rows × 59 columns)

```
uniqueid age los gender maritalstatus ...icd10  boolean_count
9166022  59  7      1   5.0              K21    1
9166022  59  7      1   5.0              N18    1
9166022  59  7      1   5.0              I12    1
9378349  77  13     2   1.0              M54    1
9378349  77  13     2   1.0              F41    1
 ....
```

I want to transpose the column icd10. Something like this:

```
uniqueid age los gender maritalstatus ...K21 N18  I12 M54 F41
9166022  59  7      1   5.0              1    1    1   0   0
9378349  77  13     2   1.0              0    0    0   1   1
```

Code

```
icd_code = df.pivot_table('boolean_count', ['uniqueid','age','los','gender', 'maritalstatus'], 'icd10')
df = pd.DataFrame(icd_code)
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Actually, I could get the desired Dataframe but the dataframe only has 7184 rows. It should have at least 108230 rows after excluding duplicates. I did cross check the dataframe with the original data and do not understand why `pivot_table` excludes those data. Is there something wrong with my code or my dataframe?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks correct.  There's no need for `df = pd.DataFrame(icd_code)`. The return of `pivot_table()` is a dataframe

I've added a cross validation at the end

1. *uniqueid    age los gender  maritalstatus* should be unique number of permutations
2. *icd10   boolean_count* are the total number of rows in dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"uniqueid":[9166022,9166022,9166022,9378349,9378349],"age":[59,59,59,77,77],"los":[7,7,7,13,13],"gender":[1,1,1,2,2],"maritalstatus":[5,5,5,1,1],"icd10":["K21","N18","I12","M54","F41"],"boolean_count":[1,1,1,1,1]})
grpcols = ['uniqueid','age','los','gender', 'maritalstatus']
df.pivot_table('boolean_count', grpcols, 'icd10')

df.groupby(grpcols).count().reset_index().assign(foo=1).groupby("foo").\
    agg({**{col:"count" for col in grpcols},
         **{col:"sum" for col in df.columns if col not in grpcols}
        })
```

**output**

As expected - 2 combinations in sample data and 5 rows

```
 uniqueid  age  los  gender  maritalstatus  icd10  boolean_count
        2    2    2       2              2      5              5
```